# Meaning of 'Particle of Mass'

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, definition, point-particles

The following quote is from Section II at http://suppes-corpus.stanford.edu/articles/physics/431.pdf

> A simple pendulum consists of a **particle of mass** $m$ hanging
>   from a...

My understanding is that the bob on the pendulum is seen as a point.

Am I correct, and could this be clarified?

Comment: Yes, I think that they meant point mass. Anyway you cannot solve the problem if the particle is not considered as a point without some informations.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object of finite size swings on the end of a string it performs two motions in space. Its centre of mass (CM) moves in a circle - this is a translation. It is also changing its orientation in space, keeping the point of attachment always towards the pivot. This is a rotation.

A finite swinging object (eg a sphere of non-zero radius) has both translational and rotational kinetic energy. The rotational KE increases as the mass is distributed further from the CM. This additional source of KE complicates the exchange energy between potential and kinetic as the pendulum swings, which affects the period of the pendulum. That is, the period of the pendulum depends on the distribution of mass (ie the **moment of inertia**) of the swinging object.

To avoid this complication the swinging object is sometimes assumed to be a point mass. This is called the **simple pendulum**. Even when a point mass rotates its rotational kinetic energy is zero because all of its mass is conentrated at zero distance from its CM. Its moment of inertia is zero. So a simple pendulum has only translational KE and no rotational KE.

When the finite size of the swinging object is taken into account (using the object's moment of inertia) it is called a **compound pendulum**.